# pass array to controller using jquery .load() function

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I'm trying to pass an array to my CI controller using the jquery `.load()` function but I'm getting this error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Missing argument 1 for QuestionQueue::update()

Filename: controllers/QuestionQueue.php

Line Number: 27

Backtrace:

File: D:\software\wamp\www\Quiz\application\controllers\QuestionQueue.php
Line: 27
Function: _error_handler

File: D:\software\wamp\www\Quiz\index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once
```

my view code:

```
$(".sortable").sortable({connectWith: '.js-connected'}).bind('sortupdate', function(e, ui) {
      var roundSize = document.getElementById("roundqs").getElementsByTagName("li").length;
      var data = new Array();
      for (i = 0; i < roundSize; i++) {
        data[i] = $('#roundqs li')[i].id;
      }

        var p = {};
        p['rId'] = <?php echo $roundRow->roundId; ?>;
        p['questions'] = data;


        $(this).load("http://<?php echo base_url();?>questionQueue/update/",p);



    });
```

my controller code:

```
public function update($data)
{
    $questionArray = $data->questions;
    $rId = $data->rId;
    $this->load->model('QuestionQueueModel');
    for ($i=0;$i<$questionArray.length;$i++){
        $this->QuestionQueueModel->updateOrAddQuestionInQueue($questionArray[$i],$rId,$i + 1);
    }
}
```

I'm pretty new to this CodeIgniter framework so it will probably be a stupid error but I can't seem to find it.

Anyone has an idea what is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the data that you're trying to pass to your controller function `update()` isn't being sent, hence the missing argument message.

Why don't you try using an `ajax` call instead to send the data to your controller ....

Like so :

```
 $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            'data' : p,
        },              
        url : 'questionQueue/update',
        success : function (data) {
            // do success handling
        },
        error : function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            // do error handling
        },
    });
```

You might need to alter the `ajax` URL to whatever it needs to be for your system, in my CI the base URL is already set so I just call the controller and then the function.

Comment: What is the default action for an ajax call? is it POST?
because I fixt my problem using an ajax call specifying the type:'POST'
and in my controller I used $this->input->post('rId');
but I couldn't use the variable in the function?? How are variables passed to the function in a controller?

Comment: Yes it is POST - you could try `$data = $_POST` inside your controller function to get the data passed. The other way you could try is appending the data to the end of the url instead, like ` url : 'questionQueue/update/' + p,`